# Error when building Angular project Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

When trying to build my (old) Angular project, I meeting this error message

```
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\me\Documents\project\dist\C:\Users\me\Documents\project\node_modules\md2\select'
```

The command line I am using is the following one

```
ng build --prod --output-path=dist --env=env --sourcemap
```

My npm version is `8.5.4` and node is `12.18.4`

I am on Windows 10

This is my dependencies (Old angular project)

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.3.6",
"@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.11",
"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.11",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^4.0.3",
"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "11.1.5",
"angulartics2": "3.3.0",
"chart.js": "^2.9.3",
"classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"cyrillic-to-latin": "^2.0.0",
"electron": "^1.8.8",
"file-saver": "^1.3.3",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"md2": "0.0.29",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"ng-spin-kit": "^5.1.1",
"ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
"ng2-img-cropper": "^0.9.0",
"outdated-browser-rework": "^2.1.3",
"rxjs": "^5.4.2",
"tinymce": "^4.6.7",
"xlsx": "^0.17.1",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"},
```

Am I missing something ? I have tried to play with npmrc file, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Use WIN+R to open a small window of operation, and then enter '.' (dot) And click OK, so that you enter the system user directory of your C drive;

After entering the system user directory, you can find the file .npmrc This file, after opening this file, you can see the [image: Prefix value]

now change whatever the prefix=xxxx value is. with the given image. And now try again.

This solved my problem. or lookup this link: https://www.programmersought.com/article/91716179653/